# string-append to files in a directory with Scheme

Tags: filesystems, scheme, tree-traversal

Please note first of all that this is a homework question so I'm not looking for straight code or anything like that, just for someone to maybe help me with my logic.

The assignment is in DrRacket. The question asks:

> Given a FileSystem, which we've defined as a structure with two fields, name and contents, where contents is a list of either directories or files; write a function that will create a ".bak" filename for every file in the directory and place it immediately after the file.

I am totally lost. My logic is as follows: If the first thing in the content list is a file, simply remake the directory with that file and a new file with ".bak" appended. This is as far as I can get - I can't see how to work things out if there's a subdirectory, OR how to go about moving further down the list.

Here's my atrocious code:

```
(define (backup my-fs)
   (cond
     [(empty? (dir-contents my-fs)) empty]
     [(file? (first (dir-contents my-fs))) (make-dir (dir-name my-fs) (append      (backup-list (first (dir-contents my-fs)))(rest (dir-contents my-fs))))]
     [(dir? (first (dir-contents my-fs))) (backup (first (dir-contents my-fs)))]))
```

Can anyone help me reason this out?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Going to have to learn how to properly do it myself!

Comment: I think we should start with an example of a valid FileSystem according to the rules in the instructions. Can you provide one showing some files and subdirectories?

Comment: I am having trouble with carriage-return... Does hitting Enter automatically post the edit/comment?

Comment: @MarkSoric -- hit shift-enter to make a newline.

Answer (score 2):

The `contents` part of your `FileSystem` is a list containing files or directories (which are lists containing ....).

This is a basic tree-traversal problem where you have three cases, as you noted:

1. list is empty
2. first element in list is a file
3. first element in list is a directory

Then you need an action for each case:

1. done
2. keep that filename, create a new filename, and continue processing the rest of the list
3. keep that directory, recursing over it, and continue processing the rest of the list

For example:

```
(define (traverse contents)
  (cond
    [(empty? contents) ... nothing to do ...]
    [(file? (first contents))              ;; if the first element's a file:
      (cons (first contents)               ;;   keep the file
       (cons (... make backup filename ... (first contents))  ;; make the backup
        (traverse (rest contents))))]      ;;   and recurse on the rest
    [(dir? (first contents)                ;; if the first element's a directory:
      (cons (traverse (first contents))    ;;   recurse on the first
            (traverse (rest contents)))])) ;;   and also recurse on the rest
```

Comment: In principle I understand what I want to do. It's the syntax of remaking a whole directory with new files in it that's got me down.

Comment: @MarkSoric -- that's what this code does.  Check out the actions for `(file? ...)` and `(dir? ...)` -- the recursion naturally takes care of remaking a whole directory.

Comment: Weird... I had something very similar code-wise when I first tried the problem and it didn't work - I obviously had a slight change that rendered what I had useless!

Comment: My issue I think is this: I can do what you did on a list, it's when I have to create the same directory structure that I'm failing.

Comment: @MarkSoric -- the natural recursion takes care of preserving the structure of the directory -- see the case for `dir?`?  It recurses not only on the rest of the list, but *also* on the first element of the list.  And then it puts the results back *in the exact same places*. If need a resource for wrapping your head around recursion, I'd suggest http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/ -- the Little Schemer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to have to massage my code a little to see if I can make it work like you're suggesting. Cheers.

Comment: @MarkSoric -- the problem I see in your code is that it doesn't recurse over the *rest* of the list, when the first element is a directory -- it only recurses over the first element.

Comment: I see... Sorry to be a pest but how does the recursion take care of the directory structure?

Comment: @MarkSoric -- it's hard to give a good explanation in a couple of sentences.  Basically, the data structure has a shape -- and the recursive function calls have to match that shape.

Comment: But I still need to construct a new structure, do I not?

Comment: The How To Design Programs textbook (also by Matthias Felleisen et al.) is *all about* this kind of problem. Specifically, Section 14. check out http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-19.html#node_chap_14

Comment: @MarkSoric -- the applications of `cons` make the new structure.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! I will have to go re-read the relevant portions of my text!

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify your data definition.  You write:

"Given a FileSystem, which we've defined as a structure with two fields, name and contents, where contents is a list of either directories or files; write a function that will create a ".bak" filename for every file in the directory and place it immediately after the file. "

This makes it clear what a FileSystem is... if you know what "directories" and "files" are. You need to clarify this by writing data definitions for "directory" and "file".  Each of these should be a separate sentence.  They might be really simple, e.g. "A file is represented as a string".

After doing this, write some examples of FileSystems.

Comment: A FileSystem is really just a Directory. It has the same structure and I use the same constructors to create it. I want to give an example of a FS and a File but I can't press Enter without posting my comment!

Comment: Okay, sounds like you've got some examples. Next, you need some test cases. There's kind of a "giving birth" moment here where you can't understand why the test cases are necessary, and then suddenly you realize that the test cases contain the solution.